# find groups of customers based on arrival times

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (around 300,000 entries) containing the columns :CustomerID, ArrivalDateTime. The data looks like this:

- Customer ID    -  ArrivalDateTime
- 0023       ------------      2018-04-29 14:01:58
- 0193       ------------       2018-02-17 18:02:32
- 0333       ------------        2017-11-05 14:14:30
- 0023       ------------      2017-10-01 14:11:45
- 0023       ------------    2018-03-17 19:04:18
- ....... ------------- .......

I want to find groups of people that visit the store together. if people arrive at the store 5 times or more on the same time and date, they should be in the same group.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected outcome

Comment: To be considered as visiting on the same date and time, is there a window of time where two customers would be in the same group (number of minutes or hours)?